# Read specific element from xml using linq

Tags: c#, linq, google-api

I'm trying to retrive postal codes using google API using c#.
how to write linq query for following xml.

```
  <address_component>
  <long_name>United States</long_name>
  <short_name>US</short_name>
  <type>country</type>
  <type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
  <long_name>94043</long_name>
  <short_name>94043</short_name>
  <type>postal_code</type>
</address_component>
```

Comment: See http://geekswithblogs.net/pabothu/archive/2014/04/29/reading-a-complex-xml-using-linq-in-c-sharp.aspx.

Comment: var res = (from el in xmlElm.Descendants("address_component")
                           where xmlElm.Value == "postal_code"
                                  select el).FirstOrDefault(); i try this but i got null result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get postal code value then:

```
var res = (from el in xmlElm.Descendants("address_component") 
           where el.Element("type").Value == "postal_code"
           select el).FirstOrDefault();
```